# comments amongst parameters in BASH

Tags: bash, comments

I want to include command-parameters-inline comments, e.g.:

```
sed -i.bak -r \
    # comment 1
    -e 'sed_commands' \
    # comment 2
    -e 'sed_commands' \
    # comment 3
    -e 'sed_commands' \
    /path/to/file
```

The above code doesn't work. Is there a different way for embedding comments in the parameters line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really want comment arguments, can try this:

```
ls $(
    echo '-l' #for the long list
    echo '-F' #show file types too
    echo '-t' #sort by time
)
```

This will be equivalent to:

```
ls -l -F -t
```

echo is an shell built-in, so does not execute external commands, so it is fast enough. But, it is crazy anyway.

or

```
makeargs() { while read line; do echo ${line//#*/}; done }
ls $(makeargs <<EOF
        -l # CDEWDWEls
        -F #Dwfwef
EOF
)
```

Comment: Nice - but note that `do echo ${line//#*/};` will work, as long as your command doesn't use the `-e` argument; if it does (like `tshark`) it will otherwise then be interpreted like an argument for `echo`, and end up missing from the output. Then you can use `printf "%s " ${line//#*/};` instead -- but that then precludes you from using stuff like `-r "$1"` for passing a filename in the arguments, as the double quotes will arrive escaped at the command (and will not be interpreted by the shell), thus messing up the filename.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using longer text blocks for your sed script, i.e.

```
sed -i.bak '
    # comment 1
    sed_commands
    # comment 2
    sed_commands
    # comment 3
    sed_commands
' /path/to/file
```

Unfortunately, embedded comments in sed script blocks are not universally a supported feature. The sun4 version would let you put a comment on the first line, but no where else. AIX sed either doesnt allow any comments, or uses a different char besides `#` for comments. Your results may vary.

I Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* invoke sed multiple times instead of passing all of the arguments to one process:

```
sed sed_commands |             # comment 1
    sed sed_commands |         # comment 2
    sed sed_commands |         # comment 3
    sed sed_commands           # final comment
```

It's obviously more wasteful, but you may decide that three extra sed processes are a fair tradeoff for readability and portability (to @shellter's point about support for comments within sed commands). Depends on your situation.

UPDATE: you'll also have to adjust if you originally intended to edit the files in place, as your `-i` argument implies. This approach would require a pipeline.

Comment: Awful idea - wastes effort copying the date through 3 pipes.

Comment: In fairness, I should add: if the files are only kilobytes in size, this is fine; if they are megabytes, getting dubious; if they are gigabytes or bigger, then 6 unnecessary copies (into and out of each of three pipes) is too expensive for comfort.

Comment: I usually try to present the minimal number of processes in a shell answer, but I mention this as an option because "awful" is relative. In 1983, sure. In 2011, as I said, it might be worth the tradeoff. You say readability isn't worth what could be a few entire milliseconds and dozens of bytes, but in some situations those crumbs may very well be worth sacrificing if notoriously cryptic regular expressions can be clarified in the script.

Comment: Sorry, you added your note about file size as I was typing my defense. Good point, and something for the OP to keep in mind.

Comment: yes, 'awful' is too strong - I left it too late to tone down the original comment; I hope the clarification atones for that in part.  The other issue you already mentioned; it's harder to overwrite the original file with a sequence of `sed` commands than with a single one.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

If you put the `\` before the `#` it will escape the comment character and you won't have a comment anymore.

If you put the `\` after the `#` it will be part of the comment and you won't escape the newline anymore.

A lack of inline comments is a limitation of bash that you would do better to adapt to than try and work around with some of the baroque suggestions already put forth.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do what you seek to do in shell plus sed.  I put the comments before the `sed` script, like this:

```
# This is a remarkably straight-forward SED script
# -- When it encounters an end of here-document followed by
#    the start of the next here document, it deletes both lines.
#    This cuts down vastly on the number of processes which are run.
# -- It also does a substitution for XXXX, because the script which
#    put the XXXX in place was quite hard enough without having to
#    worry about whether things were escaped enough times or not.
cat >$tmp.3 <<EOF
/^!\$/N
/^!\\ncat <<'!'\$/d
s%version XXXX%version $SOURCEDIR/%
EOF

# This is another entertaining SED script.
# It takes the output from the shell script generated by running the
# first script through the second script and into the shell, and
# converts it back into an NMD file.
# -- It initialises the hold space with --@, which is a marker.
# -- For lines which start with the marker, it adds the pattern space
#    to the hold space and exchanges the hold and pattern space.  It
#    then replaces a version number followed by a newline, the marker
#    and a version number by the just the new version number, but
#    replaces a version number followed by a newline and just the
#    marker by just the version number.  This replaces the old version
#    number with the new one (when there is a new version number).
#    The line is printed and deleted.
# -- Note that this code allows for an optional single word after the
#    version number.  At the moment, the only valid value is 'binary' which
#    indicates that the file should not be version stamped by mknmd.
# -- On any line which does not start with the marker, the line is
#    copied into the hold space, and if the original hold space
#    started with the marker, the line is deleted.  Otherwise, of
#    course, it is printed.
cat >$tmp.2 <<'EOF'
1{
x
s/^/--@/
x
}
/^--@ /{
H
x
s/\([   ]\)[0-9.][0-9.]*\n--@ \([0-9.]\)/\1\2/
s/\([   ]\)[0-9.][0-9.]*\([     ][      ]*[^    ]*\)\n--@ \([0-9.][0-9.]*\)/\1\3\2/
s/\([   ][0-9.][0-9.]*\)\n--@ $/\1/
s/\([   ][0-9.][0-9.]*[         ][      ]*[^    ]*\)\n--@ $/\1/
p
d
}
/^--@/!{
x
/^--@/d
}
EOF
```

There's another `sed` script in the file that is about 40 lines long (marked as 'entertaining'), though about half those lines are simply embedded shell script added to the output.  I haven't changed the shell script containing this stuff in 13 years because (a) it works and (b) the `sed` scripts scare me witless.  (The NMD format contains a file name and a version number separated by space and occasionally a tag word 'binary' instead of a version number, plus comment lines and blank lines.)

You don't have to understand what the script does - but commenting before the script is the best way I've found for documenting sed scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Although the thread is quite old i did find it for the same question and so will others. Here's my solution for this problem:

You need comments, so that if you look at your code at a much later time you will likely get an idea of what you actually did, when you wrote the code. I am just having the same problem while writing my first rsync script, which has lots of parameters which also have side effects.

Group together your parameter which belong together by topic and put them into a variable, which gets a corresponding name. This makes it easy to identify what the parameter steer. This is your short comment. In addition you can put a comment above the variable declaration to see how you can change the behavior. This is the long version comment.

Call the application with the corresponding parameter variables.

```
## Options
# Remove --whole-file for delta transfer
sync_filesystem=" --one-file-system \
                  --recursive       \
                  --relative        \
                  --whole-file      \ " ;

rsync \
      ${sync_filesystem}  \
      ${way_more_to_come} \
      "${SOURCE}"         \
      "${DESTIN}"         \
```

Good overview, easy to edit and like comments in parameters. It takes more effort, but has therefore a higher quality.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest another way that works at least in some instances:

Let's say I have the command:

```
foo --option1 --option2=blah --option3 option3val /tmp/bar`
```

I can write it this way:

```
options=(
--option1
--option2=blah
--option3 option3val
)

foo ${options[@]} /tmp/bar
```

Now let's say I want to temporarily remove the second option.  I can just comment it out:

```
options=(
--option1
# --option2=blah
--option3 option3val
)
```

Note that this technique may not work when you need extensive escaping or quoting.  I have run into some issues with that in the past, but unfortunately I don't recall the details at the moment :(

For most cases, though, this technique works well.  If you need embedded blanks in a parameter, just enclose the string in quotes, as normal.